# Preventing keyboard switching

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, switch

I know this has been addressed many times here, but without reading through all 500 results on a search, I am hoping that this is simple to solve / explain.

I live in Germany, but my mother-language is English. I have two keyboard possibilities: English & German. I ALWAYS use the German QWERTZ layout, but I installed my Win 10 in English (my wish).

There has always been a problem with the Keyboard switching back to English, but lately, it's much worse.

**My Question is:**
How do I "freeze" it onto German. I suppose I cannot remove the English layout because I have Eng. as the system language (??). How can I do this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings > Time and Language > Language > English > Options and remove the English language keyboard.  If you prefer to keep both you can use the shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch between them quickly.

Comment: Thank you, I think that worked! Sometimes Windows just gets the better of of me.